# Загрузка файла в input

Tags: selenium, node.js

У меня есть `input type="file"`, и мне нужно в него загрузить картинку. Пробую вот так:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('#edit-field-photo-und-0-upload')).sendKeys('C:\1.jpg');
```

Но ничего не происходит.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените обратный слэш в пути на прямой, вы экранировали единицу, получили мусор.